# Esper: Creating new Esper statements, and skipping those that already exist

Tags: java, validation, esper

The project I'm working on uses Esper to create monitoring rules. These rules are either active or inactive, based on a boolean in the SQL row. I would like to set up a check to see if there are any new active rules, create a statement from the, and add them to a hashmap. This will periodically run using Spring scheduler. The code so far looks like this:

```
private void refreshStatement(Rule rule) throws Expression {
    List<String> allRules = dao.getAllRules();
    for (String rule : allRules) {
        EPStatement statement = epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(rule);
        statement.addListener(new RuleListener(rule));
        ruleMap.put(rule.getId(), statement);
    }
}
```

On the initial run, this works fine. The statements are generated and added to the hashmap `ruleMap`. Upon the method running a second time due to the scheduler, though, it fails due to the first rule it sees already existing. For example:

```
ERROR [2018-08-14 12:00:00,000] org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler: Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
! com.espertech.esper.epl.expression.core.ExprValidationException: Context by name 'Test_Case' already exists
```

Is there any good way to check to see if an Esper statement already exists, and to skip the rule if it does?  So far, I've tried catching the exception and simply returning a log stating that the EPL statement already exists, that way only new statements would be created:

```
private Exception e;

private void refreshStatement(Rule rule) throws Exception {
    List<String> allRules = dao.getAllRules;
    for (String rule : allRules) {
        if (e instanceof ExprValidationException) {
            log.info("The EPL statement already exists")
        }
        else {
            EPStatement statement = epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(rule);
            statement.addListener(new RuleListener(rule));
            ruleMap.put(rule.getId(), statement);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I still got the same exception.

Edit:  I just realized that I wrote the for loop wrong.  The program will fail on when creating `statement`, and since that is in the else portion of the loop, it thus never checks for the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the currently-existing statements from `EPAdministrator.getStatementNames()` and `EPAdministrator.getStatement(String name)`.

Comparing whether a statement already exists is up to your application but `EPStatement.getText()` returns you the `EPL`.